# How to replace all vowels in a String?

Tags: ios, swift, string, flatmap

I tried with this code:

```
let vowels: [Character] = ["a","e","i","o","u", "y"]

let replaced = String(myString.map {
     $0 == vowels.contains($0) ? "1" : "0"
 })
```

But I have the error:
`Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character' and 'Bool'`

What is wrong?

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear - are you having problems with the algorithm or with the compile error?

Comment: Let's translate: So `$0` is a `Character` object. `vowels.contains($0)` returns a `Bool`. How can `someCharacter == someBool` make sense to you? Now, let's back to the topic just do `vowels.contains($0) ? "1" : "0"`, because you just care about `vowels.contains($0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just need to replace `$0 ==` with `return`, you were comparing Character with Bool it makes no sense

```
let vowels: [Character] = ["a","e","i","o","u", "y"]

let replaced = String(myString.map {
     return vowels.contains($0) ? "1" : "0"
 })
```

Comment: you can omit return  also

Answer (score 1):

replace all vowels in a String with asterisk symbol

```
let vowels: [Character] = ["a","e","i","o","u", "y"]
    var myString = "mahipal singh"
    let replaced = String(myString.map {
        vowels.contains($0) ? Character("*") : $0 // Replace * with your character you wanna to replace
    })
    print(replaced)
```

Comment: Juste one question, why if I use `vowels.contains($0) ?  $0 : Character("*")` to replace all character excepts *, all my characters are replaced by * ?

Comment: did you read comment of code ..you can set any character that you wanna to replace. i have set "*" as an example

Comment: yes , this will replace all the character excepts * if you set vowels.contains($0) ? $0 : Character("*")

Comment: It will not, it replaced ALL the characters with *, I don't understand why.

Comment: as per your condition vowels.contains($0) ? $0 : Character("*")  , it check if  vowels contain character of string it will print that vowel character and if vowels doesn't contain  that character then it will replace with * on that place

So the resultant string will be like this *a*i*a***i***  , it replace all the consonant with * and print all the vowel of string

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language `Character` is not needed `vowels.contains($0) ? "*" : $0 `

Answer (score 0):

You can remove vowel from string like so:

```
string.remove(at: string.index(where: {vowels.contains($0)})!)
```

Comment: this will remove only the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

```
let vowels: [Character] = ["a","e","i","o","u","y","A","E","I","O","U", "Y"]
var replaced = String()
for char in myString {
  if !vowels.contains(char){
    replaced = "\(replaced)\(char)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

different way but it is still as you want

```
 let strs = "hello world"
    var str = String()
    let vowles = ["e","o"]
    //if you want the index also use  this (index,char) in strs.enumerated()
    //if the index is not important use this char in strs

    for (index,char) in strs.enumerated()
{


   var who = String(char)
    if vowles.contains(who){
        print(who)
        //replace or deleted by changing the value of who
         who = ""
        str = str + who
        print(str)

    }else{
        str = str + who

    }
}
```

Comment: i thought it is better to have both,but forgot to add it though,where he chose